# My AngularJS app doesn't run in Microsoft Edge, Unknown provider

Tags: angularjs, microsoft-edge, angularjs-provider

I'm working on a web application using AngularJS.
Everything seemed to work well until I tried to run it with Microsoft Edge web-browser:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: serviceAjaxProvider <- serviceAjax <- MainCtrl
```

I created a service, called serviceAjax and never had any problem with it on Chrome or Firefox. But now that I'm trying to use my app on Edge I got this error.

My service is declared as the following :

*serviceAjax.js*

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('serviceAjax', ['$http', function ($http) {
 ...
}]);
```

And I call it like this in my controller :

*main.js*

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,serviceAjax) {
 ...
});
```

Where does this error come from, and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found out why it didn't work :

In fact it seems that IE doesn't understand everything **written in ES6**.

I used a ES6 Default Parameter :

```
function(var = value) {...};
```

**So avoid using ES6** :)

(I also had compability problems with ES6 & Firefox)

Comment: There are other options rather than 'avoid using ES6'. You can run your ES6 code through a transform (like [babel](https://babeljs.io/)) to make it ES5 compliant. Then when browsers get their act together turn of the transform. That way you dont sacrifice the awesome that is ES6.